ESLint is not reading the rules specified in the eslintrc.json in my Angular v17 Project
ESLint is not reading the rules written in the eslintrc.json file. It is displaying all the problems as errors even though I have set values of some rules as warn. Moreover, it is displaying errors for those rules whose values are set to off in eslintrc.json.
Following is my pacakage.json:-
{
  "name": "cat",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build-high": "node --max_old_space_size=7000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration production --output-hashing=all",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "serve": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 & ng serve --open",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --fix",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-prod": "node ./replace.build.js && ng build --configuration production --aot=false"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts3-angular": "^3.0.5",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.10.38",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1703.8",
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^17.3.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^17.3.11",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.104",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^30.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^30.0.0",
    "auth0-js": "^9.24.1",
    "d3": "^7.0.0",
    "d3-scale-chromatic": "^3.0.0",
    "dom-autoscroller": "^2.3.4",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "globals": "^15.8.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
    "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "ng2-dragula": "^5.1.0",
    "ngx-extended-pdf-viewer": "^20.5.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^15.2.3",
    "ngx-wig": "^17.1.7",
    "radial-progress-chart": "0.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "signalr-no-jquery": "^0.2.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript-eslint": "^7.16.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "17.5.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "17.5.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "17.5.2",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "17.5.2",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "17.5.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.3.10",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^17.3.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.9",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "7.11.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "7.11.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "globals": "^15.8.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "replace-in-file": "^6.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "~5.4.5",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  }
}


My eslintrc.json:-
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": ["projects/**/*"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": ["tsconfig.json", "e2e/tsconfig.json"],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/dot-notation": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/member-ordering": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": ["warn", {
          "selector": "default",
          "format": ["camelCase"],
          "leadingUnderscore": "allow",
          "trailingUnderscore": "allow"
        },
        {
          "selector": "variableLike",
          "format": ["camelCase"],
          "leadingUnderscore": "allow",
          "trailingUnderscore": "allow"
        },
        {
          "selector": "typeLike",
          "format": ["PascalCase"]
        }],
        "@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/prefer-for-of": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/quotes": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/semi": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/type-annotation-spacing": "warn",
        "arrow-body-style": "warn",
        "arrow-parens": ["warn", "as-needed"],
        "arrow-spacing": "warn",
        "brace-style": "warn",
        "comma-dangle": "warn",
        "comma-spacing": ["warn", { "before": false, "after": true }],
        "curly": "warn",
        "default-case": "warn",
        "default-case-last": "warn",
        "eol-last": "warn",
        "eqeqeq": "warn",
        "guard-for-in": "warn",
        "implicit-arrow-linebreak": "warn",
        "indent": ["warn", 2],
        "keyword-spacing": "warn",
        "key-spacing": "warn",
        "max-len": [
          "warn",
          {
            "code": 140,
            "ignoreComments": true,
            "ignoreRegExpLiterals": true,
            "ignoreStrings": true,
            "ignoreTemplateLiterals": true,
            "ignoreUrls": true
          }
        ],
        "no-bitwise": "warn",
        "no-console": [
          "warn",
          { "allow": ["info", "warn", "error", "time", "timeEnd", "trace"] }
        ],
        "no-debugger": "warn",
        "no-dupe-else-if": "warn",
        "no-empty": "warn",
        "no-eval": "warn",
        "no-extra-parens": "warn",
        "no-extra-semi": "warn",
        "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": "warn",
        "no-multiple-empty-lines": "warn",
        "no-multi-spaces": "warn",
        "no-shadow": "warn",
        "no-template-curly-in-string": "warn",
        "no-trailing-spaces": "warn",
        "no-unused-vars": "warn",
        "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
        "no-useless-escape": "warn",
        "no-use-before-define": "warn",
        "no-var": "warn",
        "no-whitespace-before-property": "warn",
        "prefer-arrow/prefer-arrow-functions": "warn",
        "prefer-const": "warn",
        "quote-props": "warn",
        "radix": "warn",
        "sort-keys": "off",
        "sort-vars": ["warn", { "ignoreCase": true }],
        "space-before-blocks": "warn",
        "space-infix-ops": "warn",
        "space-in-parens": "warn",
        "valid-typeof": "warn"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.html"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/template/accessibility-alt-text": "warn",
        "@angular-eslint/template/accessibility-elements-content": "warn",
        "@angular-eslint/template/accessibility-table-scope": "warn",
        "@angular-eslint/template/no-distracting-elements": "warn"
      }
    }
  ]
}


My angular.json:-
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "cat": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/Web.config",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/",
                "output": "/assets/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
              "node_modules/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css",
              "node_modules/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-balham.css"
            ],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies" : [
              "core-js",
              "core-js-pure",
              "@babel",
              "@babel/runtime/regenerator",
              "raf",
              "rgbcolor",
              "dragula",
              "pdfjs-dist",
              "file-saver",
              "html2canvas",
              "lodash",
              "radial-progress-chart",
              "signalr-no-jquery",
              "polylabel",
              "pdfmake"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "serviceWorker": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "src/ngsw-config.json",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "cat:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "cat:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "cat:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
              "node_modules/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css",
              "node_modules/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-balham.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/Web.config",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/",
                "output": "/assets/"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "cat-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "cat:serve"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}


And, my eslint.config.mjs
import globals from "globals";
import pluginJs from "@eslint/js";
import tseslint from "typescript-eslint";


export default [
  {files: ["**/*.{js,mjs,cjs,ts}"]},
  {languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser }},
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommended,
];

I desire to turn some rules off and want to display only selected ESLint problems as errors(red squiggles) and majority of errors as warnings(yellow squiggles) i.e. the problems should be displayed according to the rules set in my eslintrc.json file.

Currently you have both an eslint.config.mjs and a eslintrc.json file. One is in the flat config format, the latter is in the legacy config format. You cannot have both, one file will be respected and the other one will be ignored. ESLint implemented it so the flat config has precedence. As a consequence, everything you have written in eslintrc.json has no effect.
The quick fix is to remove the eslint.config.mjs file. In ESLint v9 the legacy config format will be not usable anymore, so you can also think about migrating the content of your eslintrc.json file into eslint.config.mjs with the help of the migration guide. However because you are still on Angular 17, and Angular ESLint v17 has no flat config support, you might run into issues. After updating to Angular ESLint v18 it should be much easier to migrate.

First of all thanks a lot for taking out your precious time to help me.
Can you please tell me why the eslint.config.mjs file was created? Did I select some wrong option when asked while adding eslint to my project using the command ng add @angular-eslint/ schematics?

@T.B.-TantiyaBichchu Good question. I just tried it out in a fresh Angular 17 project, only the .eslintrc.json file was generated when executing ng add @angular-eslint/schematics. Maybe you can check in your git history how the eslint.config.mjs file ended up in your repo?

And were the rules working in the eslintrc.json file for the project you generated?
What will be your suggestion? Should I move all the rules from eslintrc.json to eslint.congif.mjs or should I reinstall the eslint in such a way that the eslint.config.mjs don't generate?

As I explained in the answer, Angular ESLint v17 isn't ready yet for the flat config. So for the time being I would suggest to use eslintrc.json. As soon as you are using Angular v18, I would recommend to use flat config.

One more thing friend. Can you please share your eslintrc.json file here? I want to cross-check it with mine.
